# yellow dotted line grab tool

Tags: edit-mode

I'm a beginner.  Everything was going along fine. I was using click, hold, grab to pull and push on vertices without striking the <kbd>G</kbd> key.  For some reason now it's not working and when I hit the <kbd>G</kbd> key a small dotted yellow line appears and extends and contracts with my mouse movement.  What did I do?

Comment: Maybe you grab along edge. Hitting G twice does that.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender you can begin to grab either using the right mouse button or the <kbd>G</kbd> key.

After that you can move the wanted vertices, but if during this movement you hit <kbd>G</kbd> again, the movement is limited to the edges connected to the displaced vertex.

[image]

In complement, that can be used with more than one vertex, here are some behaviors :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what I did.  I accidentally hit the magnet icon in the header.  whoops

and.....I probably hit the g key twice too.  Having the best time. :-P